How to merge two main branches without creating parallel tracks?
We have a number of main branches in our git repositories:

develop: where we do our development work (based on the v2 stable branch)
v<version-number>: Stable branch for release <version-number> where 2 is our current release (aka v2).

Once we are ready to deliver from develop to e.g. the v2 main-branch we currently do the following:

git checkout develop && git pull -r:  get the latest changes
git checkout v2: Go to the current V2 branch to use that as a base branch
git checkout -b new_v2_branch && git merge develop: Merge these changes into the stable branch
<git add * &&> git commit -am "description": Commit the changes (git add only needed for new files)
git push -u origin new_v2_branch: Push the changes to a new v2 branch on bitbucket

Finally: On bitbucket create a pull-request to merge from new_v2_branch to v2
Because of this develop and v2 have different parallel "tracks" in the all-branches-graph where in fact v2 should be a label for a certain point on the develop track.
The reason for this is when we do the following:

git checkout develop && git pull -r
git checkout v2 && git merge develop
<git add * &&> git commit -am "description"
git push -u origin v2

We get an error since we are not allowed to push without pull request, since bitbucket is set up in such a way that we should review first (as is a very good thing for any normal delivery, but this is something else: we are creating a new version from develop in this case)
I have a feeling that we are missing something which would make our live easier without having to duplicate the deliveries for v2.
How can we can improve this? What should we do for these kind of deliveries?

@TTT: you are right I forgot to mention that we create that new branch from V2. Will update it in the description. I was that busy with thinking on that what we currently do causes a lot of duplication that I forgot to mention that.

The first three steps ending in git merge develop should end with develop and new_v2_branch being identical, assuming that v2 wasn't forked to start with. You can enforce this by doing git merge --ff-only develop.

Why do you ever have new changes that you need to commit with <git add * &&> git commit -am "description"? Once you do that your branches will diverge and have parallel tracks.

I'm also curious why you have git pull -r. Why rebase with -r? Are people rebasing the upstream branch? (Don't do that!)

@JohnKugelman: The git add is rarely needed, but it happened sometimes. In most cases it is just a merge & commit.
About the git pull -r that is how we were learned to do it. So it might be a bad habit ;-)
